# No Desktop after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 from 13.10

Tags: 14.04

Just reporting what appears to be a known problem with the upgrade. Fortunately I have my stuff backed up. I do not want to have to reinstall. I was working fine with 13.10 & decided to upgrade to 14.04. I should have waited to see if there might be problems. I know better and will not accept the offer so fast next time. After the upgrade completed, I could no longer bring up my desktop. The computer boots to the login prompt. I am able to enter my password for the normal user but it does not respond at all and simply shows an empty background (nothing to do further, nothing to click on).

Hopefully, this will be remedied. Please suggest me to bring back the computer to normal operations.

Comment: For me, with a similar problem, the solution was: `chown -R john /home/john` where john is your username.

Comment: Press `Alt+Ctrl+F3` -> ENTER YOUR username & password -> enter these commands-> `sudo apt-get update` -> `sudo apt-get install –reinstall ubuntu-desktop` -> `sudo apt-get install unity` -> `sudo shutdown now` -> Turn On your PC & check!

Answer (score 2):

I too came across same situation and what I did is I have Lsited below :

Login into command line mode by using ctrl+alt+(F1 to F6)

Then it will ask your username & password. With below commands I am able to get upgraded to 14.04.

```
sudo apt-get update 

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop 

sudo apt-get install unity
```