# After installing Gnome, desktop folder doesn't appear on my desktop

Tags: unity, 14.04, gnome

After installing Gnome on my 14.04 system running unity, my desktop folder (`~/Desktop`) doesn't appear on my desktop any-more. I only see the splash background that says 14.04 LTS in lower right hand corner.

I have tried [reinstalling `unity`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459586/no-desktop-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-14-04-from-13-10) and `ubuntu-desktop` but did not help.

After the Gnome installation my startup screen when the machine boots also says Ubuntu Gnome, which is not wat I was expecting. (I only installed gnome for x2go to work.)

This installation was upgraded from 12.04 also running Unity

Comment: Try enabling Desktop handling by Nautilus: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47238/how-to-enable-file-manager-to-handle-desktop-after-removing-gnome-3?rq=1

Comment: To be clear running `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true` fixed my issue. From linked question's answer.

Comment: Yes, I suppose `draw-background` would be enabled by default. :D I have flagged this as a duplicate, but if you feel the situation is different enough, please post an answer and mark it accepted.